# Double free error in my struct code

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a struct that deletes certain nodes in a list, the delete function works correctly, but I get a double free error.

I can't figure out which free is giving me the problem. I'd appreciate any help

```
struct dog* delete_from_list(struct dog *dogs)
{
    int number2 = 0;

    struct dog *temp, *cur = dogs;

    if (dogs==NULL)
    {
        printf("There are no dogs on the list \n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Enter patient number to delete: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number2);

    if (dogs->number==number2)
    {
        if(dogs->next==NULL) //only one node in the list
        {
            free(dogs);
            return NULL;
        }
        dogs = dogs->next; //moves the head to next node
        free(cur);
        return dogs;
    }
    else
    {
        while (cur->next != NULL && cur->next->number != number2)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }

        if(cur->next==NULL)
        {
            printf("Dog with number %d is not present \n", number2);
            return dogs;
        }

        temp = cur->next;
        cur->next = cur->next->next;
        free(temp);
        return dogs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since each dog has a number, I would just print the number before calling `free`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this part of your code. You should provide a complete example, i.e. how you add nodes, how you call `delete`, etc.

Comment: Debugger.....................

Comment: Every dog has its day.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double free error, try this:

- Right *after* `free`ing a pointer, set it to NULL
- Right *before* `free`ing a pointer, check if it is NULL

I would try to remove the amount of special casing, for example

```
typedef struct dog Node;

Node * delete_from_list(Node * head) {
  const int key_to_delete = GetKeyToDelete();
  if (!head) return NULL;
  for (Node * cur = head; cur; ) {
    if (cur->key = key_to_delete) {
      Node * curnext = cur->next;
      free(cur);
      cur = curnext;
    } 
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  Node * new_head = cur;
  for (Node * cur = new_head; cur; cur = cur->next) {
    if (cur->next && (cur->next->key == key_to_delete)) {
      Node * curnextnext = cur->next->next;
      free(cur->next);
      cur->next = curnextnext;
    }
  }
  return new_head;
}
```

Comment: The double free error indicates a real problem with the code (the list management). Avoiding that error by setting the pointer to NULL will just make it harder to find the real bug.

Comment: Actually, it is [well defined](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) that `free(NULL)` does nothing, so `free(NULL)` is safe.

Comment: @jdarthenay: I understand that `free(NULL)` is safe. The suggestion is to find out if OP's code is actually performing that. It *may* help to detect the real issue.